# Get automatically a CSV from external server using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a scheduled task (using cron) inside my Spring MVC application. Inside the programmed task I have to get a CSV from an external server in the following link:

http://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/observacion/ultimosdatos_6172O_datos-horarios.csv?k=and&l=6172O&datos=det&w=0&f=temperatura&x=h24

And once I get it I have to parse it.
The problem comes when getting the file, as when I click on the previous link I can download it to my computer, but I don't know how to do that using Spring.... can you give me I hint??

UPDATE: I don't have any code yet, but I guess that must be something similar to the following code:

`URL stockURL = new URL("http://example.com/stock.csv");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stockUrl.openStream()));
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(in);`

But the problem is that my URL is not exactly a .csv. Whe I put the URL in a browser it looks like it is a redirect.

Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: probably need to open an HTTP connection and then read from a buffer into a file.

Comment: can you add your code please?

Comment: Added.... the thing is that the URL is not directly the CSV so Im not sure it would do the job.

Comment: Why not put the redirect URL into your code ? The code looks OK.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments. Even if the URL doesn't have a CSV extension, i tried the following code (in Java, not Spring) but it works!!

```
URL stockURL = new URL("http://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/observacion/ultimosdatos_6172O_datos-horarios.csv?k=and&l=6172O&datos=det&w=0&f=temperatura&x=h24");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stockURL.openStream()));
    //CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(in);

    String line;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);

    }
```

So,I guess that using Spring is going to be really very similar to get the file, so thank you very much everybody!

Comment: The extension will not matter, even if you have a .jpg in it. Same applies to the content type the server might return: it is you who decides how to treat the bytes that come from the server